# Bootstrap 'npm run' errors

Tags: node.js, bootstrap-4, npm-install, npm-scripts

I installed Boostrap via npm, and then ran the `npm install` command on the folder. I get a bunch of warnings, but for the most part, it looks like it installed. Here's the output from `npm install`:

```
npm WARN deprecated qunitjs@2.4.1: 2.4.1 is the last version where QUnit will be published as 'qunitjs'. To receive future updates, you will need to change the package name to 'qunit'.
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.9: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm WARN deprecated uws@9.14.0: stop using this version
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated buildmail@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.10: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0

> fsevents@1.2.4 install /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> uws@9.14.0 install /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/uws
> node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0


> iltorb@1.3.10 install /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/iltorb
> detect-libc prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild


> node-sass@4.9.0 install /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at /Users/me/.npm/node-sass/4.9.0/darwin-x64-57_binding.node

> node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-57/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine

> nodemon@1.17.5 postinstall /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0


> sinon@4.5.0 postinstall /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/sinon
> node scripts/support-sinon.js

Have some ❤️ for Sinon? You can support the project via Open Collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/sinon/donate

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.1.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN postcss-html@0.23.7 requires a peer of postcss-syntax@^0.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN postcss-markdown@0.23.7 requires a peer of postcss-syntax@^0.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

added 1449 packages from 1470 contributors and audited 11042 packages in 45.983s
found 11 vulnerabilities (1 low, 10 moderate)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

When I try to run a command, even a simple one, like `npm run release-version`, I get a bunch of other errors. Here's a sample log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'release-version' ]
2 info using npm@6.1.0
3 info using node@v8.11.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prerelease-version',
4 verbose run-script   'release-version',
4 verbose run-script   'postrelease-version' ]
5 info lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~prerelease-version: bootstrap@4.1.1
6 info lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~release-version: bootstrap@4.1.1
7 verbose lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~release-version: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~release-version: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/.bin:/Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
9 verbose lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~release-version: CWD: /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap
10 silly lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~release-version: Args: [ '-c', 'node build/change-version.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~release-version: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~release-version: Failed to exec release-version script
13 verbose stack Error: bootstrap@4.1.1 release-version: `node build/change-version.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid bootstrap@4.1.1
15 verbose cwd /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap
16 verbose Darwin 17.5.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "release-version"
18 verbose node v8.11.2
19 verbose npm  v6.1.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error bootstrap@4.1.1 release-version: `node build/change-version.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the bootstrap@4.1.1 release-version script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I want to be able to use Bootstrap’s build tools to compile Sass. What's going on?

**Update** : Here's another example, as per a comment. The error log or `npm run css`:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'css' ]
2 info using npm@6.1.0
3 info using node@v8.11.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'precss', 'css', 'postcss' ]
5 info lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~precss: bootstrap@4.1.1
6 info lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~css: bootstrap@4.1.1
7 verbose lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~css: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~css: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/node_modules/.bin:/Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
9 verbose lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~css: CWD: /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap
10 silly lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~css: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'npm-run-all --parallel css-lint* css-compile* --sequential css-prefix* css-minify*' ]
11 silly lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~css: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle bootstrap@4.1.1~css: Failed to exec css script
13 verbose stack Error: bootstrap@4.1.1 css: `npm-run-all --parallel css-lint* css-compile* --sequential css-prefix* css-minify*`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid bootstrap@4.1.1
15 verbose cwd /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap
16 verbose Darwin 17.5.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "css"
18 verbose node v8.11.2
19 verbose npm  v6.1.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error bootstrap@4.1.1 css: `npm-run-all --parallel css-lint* css-compile* --sequential css-prefix* css-minify*`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the bootstrap@4.1.1 css script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here's what Terminal shows:

```
> bootstrap@4.1.1 css /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap
> npm-run-all --parallel css-lint* css-compile* --sequential css-prefix* css-minify*


> bootstrap@4.1.1 css-lint /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap
> stylelint --syntax scss "scss/**/*.scss"


> bootstrap@4.1.1 css-lint-docs /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap
> stylelint --syntax scss "assets/scss/*.scss" && stylelint "docs/**/*.css"


> bootstrap@4.1.1 css-compile /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap
> node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap.scss dist/css/bootstrap.css && node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap-grid.scss dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css && node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap-reboot.scss dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css


> bootstrap@4.1.1 css-compile-docs /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap
> node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 assets/scss/docs.scss assets/css/docs.min.css


> bootstrap@4.1.1 css-lint-vars /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap
> node build/lint-vars.js scss/ assets/scss/

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/build/lint-vars.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bootstrap@4.1.1 css-lint-vars: `node build/lint-vars.js scss/ assets/scss/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bootstrap@4.1.1 css-lint-vars script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2018-05-31T21_11_34_091Z-debug.log
ERROR: "css-lint-vars" exited with 1.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bootstrap@4.1.1 css: `npm-run-all --parallel css-lint* css-compile* --sequential css-prefix* css-minify*`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bootstrap@4.1.1 css script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2018-05-31T21_11_34_264Z-debug.log
```

Was the build folder supposed to be created automatically?

Comment: The PostCSS warnings are a bug that will be fixed in the next release: https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/3318

Comment: The vulnerabilities come through node-sass and will be patched in v5: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2355

Comment: Thanks, but is that why I can’t run any npm commands?

Comment: Do you have a more exact error message?

Comment: I pasted the log file of one of the errors above.

Comment: So commands like `npm run css` don't work? What error does that command give?

Comment: @Klooven I updated the question to show the error log of running `npm run css`

Comment: Are your permissions right? Is Node able to write to that folder?

Comment: @Klooven What should the permissions be? and on which folder?

Comment: In Terminal, it does show this error: `Error: Cannot find module '/Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap/build/lint-vars.js'` That folder doesn't exist. When was it supposed to be created?

Comment: Are you running the script in `/Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap`?

Comment: @Klooven In bootstrap/node_modules/bootstrap. I tried using sudo (I’m in a Mac), but same result.

Comment: Try running in the folder I specified above

Comment: @Klooven If I run it in that folder, it tells me the script doesn't exist. I think the problem is installing bootstrap from `npm install boostrap`. I have no problems when I download the source code from their site instead.

Answer (score 0):

It installed correctly, it is just warning you that bootstrap requires peer dependencies to be installed to work correctly. If you are only using bootstrap for CSS then you can ignore the warning about jQuery, the other 2 warnings have to do with other modules you have installed i.e. postcss

Comment: The problem is that I want to be able to run some of the npm commands, for example to compile Sass, but they give me errors.